# PHP - Duplicate <li>'s on foreach

Tags: php

i dont speak english but i will try get it.
My problems is on `foreach ($json->mods->$k as $name) {`  because i'm getting duplicates `<li>`:

Heres the example:

```
<ul id="1">
    <LI><B>BR:</B>
    <LI><B>BR:</B>
    <LI><B>BR:</B> Asterixmod, Explanado, Modquack</li>
    <br>
    <LI><B>DE:</B> Sweetphoenix</li>
    <br>
    <LI><B>E2:</B>
    <LI><B>E2:</B> Irishcow, Welshnutter</li>
</ul>
```

CODE:

```
<?php
echo '<ul id="1">';

$link = '.json';
$f = file_get_contents($link);
$json = json_decode($f);

if (empty($json)) {
    echo '<li id="ere"><B>ERROR</B></li>';
} else {

    foreach ($json as $key => $val) {

        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {

            foreach ($json->mods->$k as $name) {
                echo strtoupper('<li><b>' . $k . ':</b> ');
            }

            echo(implode(', ', $json->mods->$k));

            echo '</li><br>';

        }
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Hope anyone help me, ty.

Comment: Your `echo '</li><br>'` should be ouside the second `foreach` or else it executes twice each time

Comment: Can you show what your expected output is?

Comment: BR: Whoash
E2: Welshnutter
NL: Jordynl, Makinit, Yosska

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because inside your `foreach ($json->mods->$k as $name)` you are opening an `<li>`, however, you're not closing it until after that loop. This means that eg. `BR` will have 3 opening tags and one closing tag.

Furthermore, you can get the output you want with just 1 loop:

```
foreach ($json->mods as $key => $val) {

    echo '<li><b>' . strtoupper($key) . ':</b> ';

    echo implode(', ', $val);

    echo '</li><br>';

}
```

or you could even make the `echo` one line:

```
foreach ($json->mods as $key => $val) {

    echo '<li><b>' . strtoupper($key) . ':</b> ' . implode(', ', $val) . '</li><br>';

}
```

Hope this helps!